# How can I upload multiple new entries into Craft 3?

Tags: craft3, import

I want to create a few dozen new entries from an Excel or .csv import.  Does this capability exist in Craft 3?  There was a plugin for Craft 2.  But, I need to prepare for the switch to Craft 3 and this is a critical (time-sensitive) need.

Alternatively, is there another way to import a large number of new entries (using another file format, etc.)???

Thanks

Comment: You can search in the plugin store if there is a plugin that fulfill your needs. I never used any plugins from someone else and created everything on my own so I can only say depending on the data (with or without relations, how many different entry types, matrix fields and so on) it can be really fast to write a plugin by yourself. If it is only plain text it can be done within a few minutes